# How to fix bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header in serverless lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am using existing node.js express app as a serverless lambda and deployed that lambda on AWS. While running the application, I am getting errors.

**Response on screen:**

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

**Cloudwatch logs:**

```
2022-10-13T10:16:00.822Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header",
    "stack": [
        "Error: /var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)",
        "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)",
        "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/lib/generatePassword.js:1:16)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)"
    ]
}
```

**handler.js**

```
'use strict';

const app = require('./app');
const serverless = require('serverless-http')

module.exports.invokeServer = serverless(app)
```

**serverless.yml**

```
service: saac-login
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  timeout: 15
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.invokeServer
    events:
      - http: ANY /{proxy+}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong going on in this? While running the node.js server, its working fine.

Comment: Where are you building the code that you're deploying to Lambda, and is that using the same architecture as what your Lambda function is using? Sounds like a possible incompatability issue .

Comment: @monkee I am simplifying running the above code to deploy the code on lambda. I am using the command: ```serverless deploy```